# Determine if record exists where two fields must match in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, record

I have a table (and a corresponding class) for this solution that has only two fields a UserId and a TicketId.  Now I need to test if a record exists in this table where the UserId matches the logged in individual and TicketId matches the passed value.  This is the code I tried:

```
bool subscriptionExists = db.TicketSubscriptions.Any(ts => ts.TicketId.Equals(db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TicketNumber == ticketNumber).TicketId))
     .Where(ts => ts.UserId == db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NTUserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).UserId);
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> 'bool' does not contain an extension method for 'where' and no
>   extension method 'where' accepting a first argument of type 'bool'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?

Am I on the right track? or is there a much better way to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Where` on a `bool` value instead of a `List`. `Any()` returns `bool`. You can try like following. Hope this will help you.

```
var ticketId=db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t =>t.TicketNumber==ticketNumber).TicketId;
var userId=db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.NTUserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).UserId;

bool subscriptionExists = db.TicketSubscriptions.
                          Any(ts => ts.TicketId.Equals(ticketId) && ts.UserId == userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the .Where on the result of the .Any, which is a boolean value.  Try combining your clauses and then calling .Any on the whole thing:

```
bool subscriptionExists = db.TicketSubscriptions.Any(
        ts => ts.TicketId.Equals(db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TicketNumber == ticketNumber).TicketId) && 
              ts.UserId == db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NTUserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).UserId);
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that `Any()` returns a `bool`, so you can't call `Where()` on it.

`Where`, returns another `IEnumerable`, so if you put `Where` before `Any()`, you won't have that problem.

You can also put both conditions inside the `Any()` I.E. `someEnumerable.Any(/*condition1*/ && /*condition1*/);`

---

on another note, I'd make use of Navigation Properties if I were you.  You can google search for "navigation properties" and the name of whatever database framework you're using(like entity framework or linq to sql) to find more information.

That will let you do things like

```
subscriptionExists = db.TicketSubscriptions
    .Any(ts => ts.Ticket.TicketNumber == ticketNumber 
      && ts.User.NTUserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

---

on yet another note, I believe that `User.Identity` is going to have the user id, so you don't even have to bother accessing the users table like that.  Intellisence can help you find out how to access that.

Answer (score 0):

`TicketSubscriptions.Any()` returns a Bool.

It is result is a True or False. So you cannot continue to query with a where. Write the code more readable. You can see mistakes easier. In `any()` function you need a boolean statement like if statements. You can use `||` or `&&` signs simply.

```
var userId = User.Identity.Name;
var passedValue = ... // I dont know if it is from a parameter.

bool subscriptionExists = TicketSubscriptions.Any(ts => ts.NTUserName == userId && ts.TicketId == passedValue );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Complementing the  @Azim answer**

When you use .FirstOrDefault must verify returned values. Otherwise if you have sure that the return value never is null must use .First

```
        var ticketId=db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t =>t.TicketNumber==ticketNumber).TicketId;
        varuserId=db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.NTUserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).UserId;

        if(ticketId != null && userId != null)
        {

              bool subscriptionExists = db.TicketSubscriptions.
                                  Any(ts => ts.TicketId.Equals(ticketId) && ts.UserId == userId)
        }
```